# box-shadow weird behavior in Box component from Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I was developing an application and I wanted to render list of items.
The state is simple, an array of elements with a name, an identifier and a `selected` key that will be used by each item to show a set of special styles if the item is selected.
I'm using material-ui, and each item is a `Box` component. Each `Box` component has an `OnClick` handler to select it, but I realized that when I select an item, only a few styles from it have changed and `box-shadow` changes didn't apply.

```
import React from "react";
import "./index.css";
import { Grid, Box } from "@material-ui/core";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const Item = withStyles({
  root: {
    width: "200px",
    height: "200px",
    boxShadow: props => {
      if (props.selected) {
        return "4px 4px 24px 2px blue;";
      }

      return "4px 4px 24px 2px red";
    },
    backgroundColor: props => {
      if (props.selected) {
        return "lightblue";
      }

      return "orange";
    },
    border: props => {
      if (props.selected) {
        return "solid 4px blue";
      }

      return "solid 4px black";
    },
    marginLeft: "100px"
  }
})(Box);

class Testing extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [
        {
          name: "one",
          selected: true,
          identifier: "first"
        },
        {
          name: "two",
          identifier: "second",
          selected: false
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  selectItem(selectedIdx) {
    this.setState(state => ({
      items: state.items.map((item, idx) => {
        if (idx === selectedIdx) {
          return {
            ...item,
            selected: true
          };
        }

        return {
          ...item,
          selected: false
        };
      })
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Grid container direction="row">
        {this.state.items.map((item, idx) => (
          /**
           * In this case only apply styles for border and background-color, box-shadow
           * doesn't have effect when you click the second element.
           */
          <Item
            key={item.identifier}
            selected={item.selected}
            onClick={() => this.selectItem(idx)}
          />
          /*
            * This case works properly.
            <Item key={`${item.identifier}-${item.selected}`}
            selected={item.selected}
            onClick={() => this.selectItem(idx)} />
          */
        ))}
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return <Testing />;
}
```

Live example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-bogdan-mcb0z
In that example the actual `<Item>` code doesn't work (it doesn't update `box-shadow` styles) and commented `Item` code works properly, could you explain me why `box-shadow` changes work properly in this code:

```
<Item key={`${item.identifier}-${item.selected}`}
  selected={item.selected}
  onClick={() => this.selectItem(idx)} />
```

but not on:

```
<Item
  key={item.identifier}
  selected={item.selected}
  onClick={() => this.selectItem(idx)}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your return statement in `boxShadow`

#### FROM

```
return "4px 4px 24px 2px blue;";
```

#### TO

```
return "4px 4px 24px 2px blue";
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-star-c8k68)

> **Why it is working with key={`${item.identifier}-${item.selected}`}**

The answer is **NO**, It was not working. You were just toggling the key position if you see in `React Dev Tools`. With new keys each time, you are shaking the whole tree which causing `re-rendering`.

Comment: Thanks, you solved my problem!, do you know if this could be a kind of bug from material-ui lib ?

Comment: Since it was an invalid style string, It shouldn't take it on initial render though. Need to go into depth. As of now, I don't have any solid answer. Sorry pal